# Remove animation jump when collapsing

Tags: html, css

Menu have little jump before and after collapse. I tried fix it with margins but didnt worked. I used bootstrap. I want to remove this and make animation smooth.

Here the header html code:

```
<header>
    <div>         
        <nav class="navbar bg-lightt navbar-expand-xxlg">
            <div class="navbar navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav mx-auto">

                    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Projects</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>

                </ul>

            </div>

            <div class="mx-auto">

                <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbar">
                    <span class="menu-button">MENU</span>
                </button>

            </div>

        </nav>

    </div>

</header>
```

To see that jump add css or animation .collapsing:

```
.collapsing 
{
    transition-property: height, visibility;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}

.nav.navbar-nav.nav li a 
{
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: auto;
    color: black;
}

.navbar-toggler, 
.navbar-toggler-icon, 
.navbar-toggler:active, 
.navbar-toggler:focus
{
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
    margin: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this code

```css
.collapsing 
{
    transition-property: height, visibility;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}

.nav.navbar-nav.nav li a 
{
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: auto;
    color: black;
}

.navbar-toggler, 
.navbar-toggler-icon, 
.navbar-toggler:active, 
.navbar-toggler:focus
{
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
    margin: none;
}
.navbar-collapse{
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800&subset=cyrillic,cyrillic-ext,greek,greek-ext,latin-ext,vietnamese" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
    <div>         
        <nav class="navbar bg-lightt navbar-expand-xxlg">
            <div class="navbar navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav mx-auto">

                    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Projects</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>

                </ul>

            </div>

            <div class="mx-auto">

                <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
                    <span class="menu-button">MENU</span>
                </button>

            </div>

        </nav>

    </div>

</header>
</body>
```